# Swift: write a function that allocates an instance of (any) class

Tags: objective-c, swift, class, instance

I'm looking for the equivalent of the following Obj-C code in Swift:

```
- newInstanceOf:(id)classRef {
    return [classRef new];
}
```

and then to use it:

```
id instance = [whatever newInstanceOf:NSArray.class]
[instance isKindOfClass:NSArray.class] == YES
```

I have tried using a Swift template:

```
func newSomething<T>(classRef:T.Type) -> T {
    return classRef()
}
```

I get the error: `error: 'T' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers`

Comment: I'm trying to understand why you'd want to do this. What does `whatever` represent in `[whatever newInstanceOf:NSArray.class]`, and why is `newInstanceOf` an instance method rather than a class method?

Comment: No particular reason, I just didn't want to write a C function that uses Obj-C objects to confuse the matter even more. I want to do this f.ex. to make a generic object factory that takes the class as an argument.

Comment: It's still unclear what you're trying to achieve. How is `[whatever newInstanceOf:NSArray.class]` an improvement on `NSArray()`? And why would a factory method be an instance method rather than a class method, as I asked previously?

Comment: You can use NSArray.class as a variable. f.ex.:
[self createInstanceOf:self.classThatWasDefinedAtRuntime]
where self.classThatWasDefinedAtRuntime is previously set by a 3rd party

Answer (score 0):

You could create a protocol to act as a type constraint for objects initializable by a void-argument initializer, and thereafter extend your types of choice to this protocol.

```
protocol SimplyInitializable {
    init()
}

extension Int : SimplyInitializable { }
extension Double : SimplyInitializable { }
extension String : SimplyInitializable { }

struct MyStruct {
    var myInt : Int
    init() {
        myInt = 0
    }
}
extension MyStruct : SimplyInitializable { }

func newSomething<T: SimplyInitializable>(classRef: T.Type) -> T {
    return classRef.init()
}

/* Examples */
var a = newSomething(Int)
var b = newSomething(Double)
var c = newSomething("".dynamicType)
var d = newSomething(MyStruct)
var e = newSomething(a.dynamicType)

print(a.dynamicType) // Int
print(b.dynamicType) // Double
print(c.dynamicType) // String
print(d.dynamicType) // MyStruct
print(e.dynamicType) // Int
```

Comment: I noticed each 'extension * : SimplyInitializable { }' doesn't contain any actual code, because init() exists in every class anyway. Is there a way to do this without adding an 'extension..' to each class I want this to work with?

Comment: @bamalex Yes exactly. I'm don't know of a way to extend several types to the same protocol at once, not sure if it's possible, but perhaps someone else can help out with that.

Answer (score 0):

Actually in Swift, not all classes are guaranteed to have an init() initializer.  It can work with NSObject classes though because NSObject does have that requirement.

```
func newInstanceOf<T:NSObject>(aClass:T.Type) -> NSObject
{ return aClass.init() }

let string = newInstanceOf(NSString)   // ""
let date   = newInstanceOf(NSDate)     // 2016-01-15 05:27:29 +0000
```

Comment: Then perhaps there's a way to form the <T:NSObject>(aClass:T.Type) part of the definition to allow the caller to do something like this: 
newInstanceOf(SomeClass as! SimplyInitializable)